# c++ : double free or corruption error for delete an string object on an reallocted memory

Tags: c++

When manage your own linear memory, you will encounter the need to call realloc function to expand your memory. But when the destructor of the string object is called in the new memory space, it will crash. But if it is another type such as vector, there will be no problem. Excuse me, why is this? The code is as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    char *p = (char *)malloc(512);

    // error code
    new(p) string("foo");
    cout << *reinterpret_cast<string *>(p) << endl;
    p = (char *)realloc(p, 1024);
    string *k = reinterpret_cast<string *>(p);
    k->~string();

    // ok code
    //new(p) vector<string>(2, "foo");
    //cout << (*reinterpret_cast<vector<string> *>(p))[0] << endl;
    //p = (char *)realloc(p, 1024);
    //vector<string> *k = reinterpret_cast<vector<string>*>(p);
    //k->~vector<string>();

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that STL usually allocates new memory, and then move the old objects to the new memory. But the memory I manage can store many types, so I need to call the constructor and destructor of the corresponding type when expanding. The code writing is a bit complicated, so I want to use realloc to be lazy.

Comment: you can't use `realloc` on a non-trivial type, it makes no sense to `realloc` a `std::string` anyway, its a fixed size

Answer (score 0):

What you describe does not work with strings, but will generally *not work* with most c++ objects.  Even when it appears to work with `std::vector` it still is undefined behavior, and your expectations of "no problem" are unwarranted.  UB may result in ways that look correct, but you cannot rely on that, or expect it to continue to work in the future.

For any type you use in your memory scheme described, such as std::string, the following must compile:

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<std::string>);
```

If the above doesn't compile, it is *not safe* to use in your memory scheme.

Think of trivial types as a c-style struct.  They don't *do* anything, but only hold simple data, or compositions of simple data, and are safe to move around with `memcpy`.

The requirements on what is trivial are as follows, from cppreference:

> The following types are collectively called trivially copyable types:
>
> Scalar types
>
> Trivially copyable classes, i.e. classes satisfying following requirements:
> At least one copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator is eligible
>
> ```
>    Every eligible copy constructor (if any) is trivial
>
>    Every eligible move constructor (if any) is trivial
>
>    Every eligible copy assignment operator (if any) is trivial
>
>    Every eligible move assignment operator (if any) is trivial
>
>    Has a trivial non-deleted destructor
> ```
>
> Arrays of TriviallyCopyable objects
>
> This implies that a trivially copyable class has no virtual functions or virtual base classes.

A new type trait, *is_trivially_relocatable* may exist in the future, and be a more specific test and a few more types will be eligible but it does not exist in c++ today.

So why does std::string fail?  Every one of the above requirements for triviality fails.  It manages its own memory internally, and so its copy and move functionality is not trivial.  The problem is easily visible because strings have the Small Buffer Optimization, which means it may store pointers internally to itself, and moving them via memcpy fails to update its internal state to its new location.

What makes a copy constructor non-trivial?  Again from cppreference:

> The copy constructor for class T is trivial if all of the following are true:
>
> it is not user-provided (that is, it is implicitly-defined or defaulted) ;
> T has no virtual member functions;
> T has no virtual base classes;
> the copy constructor selected for every direct base of T is trivial;
> the copy constructor selected for every non-static class type (or array of class type) member of T is trivial;

In short, you really are very limited in what you can use in your highly error-prone approach, and you probably should consider something entirely different.